# How to declare function that returns an array of object?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Just getting started on python (coming from .Net). I'm trying to figure out how to declare a function that returns a list of object:

```
class myObj:
  def __init__(self):
    self.myValue1: int=1
    self.myValue2: float=2.1

class myOwner:
  def __init__(self):
    self.myListofObj: myObj=[]

  def getMyListOfObj(self): # <== Here
    return self.myListOfObj
```

1. In the `getMyListOfObj()` declaration, how do I hint to IDE (Pycharm) that this method will return an `array` of `myObj` instead?  For example, if I do:

   xx = [a of a in newOwner.getListOfObj()]

Pycharm will think that it is returning `myObj object`, instead of an `array`. I know of:

```
def getMyListOfObj(self) -> []:
```

but that doesn't indicate that it is an `array of myObj`, just an `array`.

2. On the line declaring `self.myListofObj: myObj=[]`, is this the correct way to declare an `array` of `myObj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2. Nope, your annotation means that `self.myListOfObj` is `myObj`.

Mark it in the following way: `self.myListOfObj: typing.List[myObj] = []`

1. Please check [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484)

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import TypeVar, List
```

1. def getMyListOfObj(self) -> List[myObj]:
2. 

```
self.myListofObj: List[myObj]=[]
```

Or you can simplify the use of Types using `TypeVar`.

```
T = TypeVar('T')
def getMyListOfObj(self) -> List[T]:
```

Ref:

[Support for type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

[PEP 483: Type Hints](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/)